# How to change grey color of icons in "more" uitableview on ios 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In ios 7 if you have more than 4 items in uitabbar, the other will be put in a "more" table view. How do I change the ***color*** of the icon in that view? I use this code to set icons in my appdelegate.m, but they appear greyed as in photo.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem;
UIImage *unselectedImage;
UIImage *selectedImage;
tabBarItem = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];
unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_photo.png"];
[tabBarItem setImage: [unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem setSelectedImage: [selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the global tint color of your app:

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor XXXX]];
```

Comment: ok, you're my hero. This solves the problem. There's no cleaner way to do that? I can't imagine what else can be affected by such a radical change...

Comment: isn't `tintColor` a `UIView`'s property. You can try set it on the tab bar.

Comment: Yeah you could, but you probably want your entire app to have the same look/feel

Comment: I'm not quite sure ^^